# Does any file system implement Copy on Write mechanism for CP?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, xfs, copy-on-write

We have seen OS doing Copy on Write optimisation when forking a process. Reason being that most of the time fork is preceded by exec, so we don't want to incur the cost of page allocations and copying the data from the caller address space unnecessarily.

So does this also happen when doing CP on a linux with ext4 or xfs (journaling) file systems? If it does not happen, then why not?

Comment: Copy-on-Write is implemented on ZFS, and it has indeed very cheap filesystem/volume clones. ext4/xfs have too primitive on-disk format, I believe, to support that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The keyword to search is `reflink`.  It was recently implemented in XFS.

EDIT: the XFS implementation was initially marked EXPERIMENTAL.  This warning was removed in the kernel release 4.16, a number of months after I wrote the above :-).

Comment: in 5.11 it's supported in Btrfs, CIFS, NFS 4.2, OCFS2, overlayfs, and XFS

Answer (score 20):

From `cp` [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/cp.1.html):

> When --reflink[=always] is specified, perform a lightweight copy, where the data blocks are copied only when modified.  If this is not possible the copy fails, or if --reflink=auto is specified, fall back to a standard copy.

This works on file systems which support *Copy-on-Write* (*reflink*), mainly BTRFS at the moment. XFS reflink implementation is in development <sup>[[1]](https://lwn.net/Articles/659677/)[[2]](https://lwn.net/Articles/702633/)</sup>.

Comment: Some network file systems like NFS, CIFS, OCFS2 may pass those along to the server as well.

Answer (score 7):

Linux has a system call that allows userspace processes to tell the kernel to make copy on write copies of files.  FICLONERANGE and FICLONE used as options to ioctl allow copy on write copies of files and ranges within files to be made.

This is used by cp --reflink to make the copies where the file system supports this.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you introduce a syscall for `cp` (or at least to copy a block), the OS has a hard time figuring out that the data the `cp` program is going to write is the same as the one it just read from another block. On top of that, you'd have additional overhead to manage the "several files share the same blocks" scenario. Large similar files that only differ in few blocks happen rarely. So it's cheaper on the whole to just copy those blocks, then to add this administrative overhead to *all* files.

Now if you "copy" files (lots of them) by adding another clone/snapshot of the file system in, say, BTRFS, the situation is different: Now you've "copied" *all* files in the filesystem, and any changes to them will be copy-on-write. This exists, but not in ext4.

"Journalling" is a completely independent concept from that, it's the administrative structures for the files that count.

Comment: Large files one being a binary copy of the other extremely rare times differ in a single bit and whin it happen is due to an error.

Comment: A system call for copy has been introduced (see my answer).